# Missing database connections eclipse

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, jboss, connection

I am missing MySQL and other connection profiles in eclipse so that JBoss server throws errors. Unable to post image because of reputation ;)

I do have only:

- Generic JDBC
- HSQLDB

Using Eclipse Kepler and jboss eap 6.1 - already established MySQL server on my PC.

Comment: [Creating a Database Connection Profile](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.doc.user%2Fdoc%2Fhtml%2Fasc1229700344899.html)...

Comment: Had the same problem!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First, if you are going to do any Java web application development on eclipse, please make sure you are using Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers. This will get most relevant plugins already installed and prevents you from downloading any further plugins.

You can download additional connection profiles via the DTP (Data Tools Platform) plugin. Either via "Eclipse Marketplace", Search for DTP or "Install New Software...", Enter your eclipse version in the "Work with: " field (in this case "Kepler ") and look for the Database Development > Data Tools Platform Enablement Extender SDK"

Comment: Thanks, from what I remember that was a solution. :) Sorry for accepting the answer so late- I didn't log in for quite a while...