# Eclipse - How to create SQL File?

Tags: eclipse, spring-starter

I am currently working on a Spring Starter project. I tried to add/create a SQL file to/in my resources folder. But when searching for "SQL File" I did not get a result. I also looked for something suitable in Eclipse Marketplace but I did not find anything. I only get solutions like SQL Editor, DBeaver - SQL Debugger, SQL DAL Maker or Eclipse uroboroSQL Formatter when I search for SQL... Or is there maybe a workaround to solve this?

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by following the answer here: [Missing database connections eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27384509/missing-database-connections-eclipse)

I downloaded additional connection profiles via the DTP (Data Tools Platform) plugin. I did it via "Install New Software...", entered my eclipse version in the "Work with: " field (in this case "Kepler ") and looked for the Database Development > Data Tools Platform SQL Development Tools".